# c# mvc return AddModelError from different model view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, error-handling

I wanna return

```
ModelState.AddModelError("", "The data provided is incorrect.");
```

However, my View is using different model...this is my View

```
@model ToiletSurvey.Models.adminAptmnt

<!DOCTYPE html>

<div id="content">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-4">
        <h1 class="page-title txt-color-blueDark">
            <i class="fa fa-table fa-fw "></i>
            e-Booking : Rumah Rehat Syarikat - GENTING
        </h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my controller is this:-

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include ="Id,RInfo_id,apartmentID")]    BookingInformationModels BookingInfo, FormCollection form, int RIid)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        BookingInfo.apartmentID = "GT";
        ...
        bool dateExists = db.BookingtInformationModels.Any(m => m.AptUnit.Equals(AUnit) && m.DaftarMasuk.Equals(DftarMsk));
        if (dateExists)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The data provided is incorrect.");
        }
        else
        {
            db.BookingtInformationModels.Add(BookingInfo);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    return View(BookingInfo);
}
```

However it return an error message

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'ToiletSurvey.Models.BookingInformationModels', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'ToiletSurvey.Models.adminAptmnt'.

How am I suppose to return `AddModelError` as an error message and not saving the form.

Comment: What is the name of that view? And why are you returning a view for a different model?

Comment: @StephenMuecke The view is displaying data from adminAptmnt model, and assign it to my bookingInfo controller. Is there any other ways on displaying or alerting the error message?